# how to revertFlip of two cards that are not the same?

Tags: jquery

i am using flip plugin of jquery. i would like to flip a card(div), after it finished to flip,immediately to revertFlip it. that what i tried:

```
$("#flipbox").bind("click",function(){
        $(this).flip({
            direction:'tb',
            onEnd: function() {
                $(this).revertFlip();
                console.log('when the animation has already ended');

            }
        })
    }
```

Do you have any idea?

Thanks.

Comment: How is that not working ? What error do you get ?

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues to take into account here. When `onEnd` is being called and how `revertFlip()` works.

`onEnd` fires when the animation ends, but not when the logic of the functions ends, meaning a call to `revertFlip()` will not fire!

`revertFlip()` also has the `onBefore`, `onAnimation` and most importantly `onEnd` events, meaning a simple revert will loop indefinitely.

To fix the first issue, just set a timeout/delay.

To fix the second issue, you could use a boolean value.

```
$("#flipbox").bind("click",function(){
    var flip=true;
    $this=$(this);
    $this.flip({
        direction:'tb',
        onEnd:function(){
            if(flip){
                flip=false;
                setTimeout(function(){$this.revertFlip();},200);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here's an [example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Khez/nWzx4/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems your plugin calls the callback a bit too early to handle revertFlip correctly. The only simple workaround I see here is to give the plugin the time it needs...

This does work:

```
var flag = false;
$('#flip').flip({
    direction: 'tb',
    onEnd: function() {
        if(!flag) {
            // 400ms should do the trick.
            setTimeout(function(){ $('#flip').revertFlip(); }, 400); 
            flag = true;
        }
    }
 });
```

The purpose of the `flag` stuff is to prevent infinite recursive callbacks on `onEnd`.